# how to show all record with AJAX and JSON

Tags: php, ajax, json, laravel

i use Laravel 4.2.0. i want to create form search,
here's my code in blade.php :

```
var date1 = $('[name=date1]').val();
var date2 = $('[name=date2]').val();
$.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: "{{URL::to('filterCode')}}",
   data: "date1="+date1+"&date2="+date2, 
   dataType: 'json',
   success: function(data){
      console.log(data.code);                     
   }
});
```

here's code **filterCode** in controller :

```
$date1 = Input::get('date1');
$date2 = Input::get('date2');

$filter = DB::table('orders')
                ->whereBetween('orders.date',array($date1,$date2))
                ->get();
foreach ($filter as $f) {
    $data = array('code' => $f->code);
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

record in database :

```
----------------------
| code  |    date    |
----------------------
| A001  | 2015-01-08 |
----------------------
| A002  | 2015-01-18 |
----------------------
| A003  | 2015-01-20 |
----------------------
```

if I choose the date 2015-01-08 until 2015-01-10 it will display the code A001.
if I choose the date 2015-01-08 until 2015-01-18 it should be show the code A001 until A002.
but it's doesn't show anything. Can you help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this on your controller.

```
$date1 = Input::get('date1');
$date2 = Input::get('date2');

$filter = DB::table('orders')
                ->whereBetween('date',array($date1,$date2))
                ->get();
$data = [];
foreach ($filter as $f) {
    $data = array_add($data, 'code', $f->code);
}
return Response::json(['data' => $data]);
```